# How to decouple game physics from objects

Tags: game-physics

My game objects generally look like this in a `pseudo-javascript` fashion:

```
function Player(){
    this.update = function() {
        //logic that should be run per update frame
        //physics code I really don't want here
    }
}
Player.prototype = new gameObject;
```

`Player.update` is called by a `gameObjectManager` that instantiated it, which is basically an array that loops through calling `update()` on all objects in it.  Fine, this works well enough for update functions that are specific to the object itself.

What I don't want in that function is physics logic.  It's causing unnecessary bloat in my code and I'm finding that I have to duplicate a lot of functionality in each unique `gameObject` I create.  Finding the appropriate class to put this in is difficult, because not all of my `gameObjects` need it.

One solution I have toyed with is another class like `gameObjectManger`, cleverly named `physicsManger`, which will maintain an array of objects that require physics updates, and act upon them directly instead of calling `update()` for each.

Or, maybe that code should go into `gameObjectManager` itself, I don't know.

My goal is to make applying physics to any arbitrary object in the `gameworld` be as easy as setting

```
player.physics = true;
```

The objects ideally should not know or care about physics code, just that they can be acted upon by it.

Comment: So just create a function called `DoPhysics()` or something and call that function to do all your physics logic.

Comment: In GameObjectManager, specify an updatePhysics() function, that maintains or sorts the list of objects that has the setting 'player.physics = true', and update their physics, within that function.

Comment: You may also want something like a struct for PhysicsSettings that includes the mass, buoyancy, friction, lift, whatever's appropriate for what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to just separate it to two functions. Have a `updateLogic()` function and an `updatePhysics()` function. Then for physicsless objects leave the `updatePhysics()` function empty. You could add a `physicsObjectManager` if you like, but I would just have your `gameObjectManager` call each function for each object.

I'm presuming that by 'bloating my code' you mean in terms of reading and maintaining it, not in terms of performance. I highly recommend using **helper functions** more often (subdividing a function into smaller, reusable component functions) if you find you are writing **similar or identical code often**.

I don't know what language you are developing in, but this also sounds like a perfect time to use **Object Inheritance**. This will make your classes much **less redundant**, and more structured. You may also find that using inheritance also makes the project **easier** for you to understand and work effectively with.

Comment: I do have my player inherit from visualGameObject (screen drawing functions), which inherits from gameObject (generic container objects in game world space).  I'd guess that I could create one more class above gameObject, but then if I have a visualGameObject that shouldn't be a physicsObject, or a physicsObject that shouldn't draw on screen (wind, invisible walls, elevators, gravity wells), what do I do then? This is where inheritance gets sticky for me.

Comment: I can see why that approach would be problematic. My suggestion is **flipping that around**. Your top level class is a `gameObject`. This is extended by `visualGameObject`. Now take `visualGameObject` and extend THAT. For instance, make an `animal` class that extends `visualGameObject`. Perhaps animals have repetitive movement physics. Then you can make a `wolf` and a `deer` for instance that extend both `animal` but have different logic functions. Sorry I'm making up game things, I don't know what your game classes are, or where the repetition is.

Comment: This illustration may help. For instance, a Player may have quite a lot in common with an Enemy (maybe they both walk, or shoot things). Those commonalities can go in the Agent class. This doesnt mean you have to use generic Agents in your game, just that you don't have to do the logic for walking and shooting separately for Players and Enemies if they have the same behavior in those ways.

http://bhattaca.github.io/cse2122/images/class-diagram-no-methods.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I threw away the idea that I needed prototypical inheritance to implement my physics code.  What I ended up with is a simple `Physics` function in the global namespace that expects to operate on any `GameObject` containing coordinates and other physics properties.

I can invoke it anywhere in my other code to operate on any object I like using `Physics.call(object, deltaTime)`

This gave me the flexibility I was looking for, so I will be using this method instead of prototypical inheritance.